# Can I use a Spearman Rank-Order Correlation test to check the impact of potential confounders in my data?

Tags: nonparametric, spearman-rho

I have a relatively basic statistics knowledge, so I apologise in advance if this question doesn't fully make sense or if I'm totally off-base with how I'm trying to analyse it.

I've got a project that is essentially looking at reaction time in a pre/post manner to assess the impact of a treatment (using a variant of a psychomotor vigilance task - basically 75 participants each did a 5-minute reaction time task pre-treatment and again post-treatment, and with each run generated approximately 35-40 reaction time 'trials'). My alternative hypothesis is that post-treatment median reaction time is greater than pre-treatment median reaction time.

Because each trial has a 'time-out' at 1000 ms (and based on some previous literature using similar tests), I've used median reaction time as my measure of central tendency rather than the mean.

I checked my data in R using a Q-Q plot and the Shapiro-Wilk test and it does not satisfy the assumption of normality. Therefore, for my primary outcome, I used a one-sided paired Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test:

preTime = median pre-treatment reaction time for each participant.

postTime = median post-treatment reaction time for each participant.

In R, I entered wilcox.test(preTime, postTime, paired=TRUE, alternative = c("less")),

which allowed me to reject the null hypothesis with *p* = 0.03757.

My question is regarding analyzing the impact of potential confounders (such as age, number of previous treatments). Is it appropriate to calculate the difference between median reaction times for each participant (x = preTime - postTime), and use that as the variable for this analysis?

I was thinking of using a Spearman rank-order correlation test (age vs. difference between median reaction time, and # of previous treatments vs. difference between median reaction time) for this purpose, but a friend of mine was telling me that I might need to do more complicated regression modelling using pre- and post- times as a covariate, which is definitely above my level of understanding.

Any help would be appreciated! Hopefully I provided enough information and a clear enough question...

Comment: Yes, a little  more information would be helpful.  Do you plan to use both your pre and post scores in evaluating the impact of age, etc?  Also, what do you mean by "difference between median reaction time"?

Comment: So what I've done is calculated the median reaction time for each participant pre-treatment (for participant x, lets call this PreTime[x]) and post-treatment (PostTime[x]).
I then calculated the "change in median reaction time" (call it ChangeTime[x]) which is:
ChangeTime[x] = PreTime[x] - PostTime[x], which is what I'm referencing by "difference between median reaction time". 

I've currently used Spearman rank correlation to check for associations between age and ChangeTime[x], # of treatments and ChangeTime[x], etc. rather than using both the pre/post scores directly to evaluate the impact.

Comment: I'm just not sure whether that is statistically valid or whether I should actually be looking at the pre and post scores directly to evaluate the impact of age (as I'm assessing the impact of the treatment itself, I'm not concerned per se with where the patient's baseline is, but rather with how much it changes post-treatment). Hopefully that helps clarify things!

Comment: Since you are interested in change, not level, then analyzing the change score for each person makes sense.  Perhaps there are more sophisticated analyses than yours, perhaps with greater power or able to detect more subtle relationships, but your approach is logically sound, as I see it.  To see if there might be more subtle relationships, you might try plotting your data in various ways.  Perhaps others might chime in on this as well.